# Load Image outside src-Folder: NullPointerException

Tags: javafx

I have tried different variants to load images in JavaFX.

Two variant work.
Example here:

Image in same-Package als Main:

```
    new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("gesicht.png");
```

Image in img-Package but inside src-folder:

```
    Image img = new 
    Image(getClass().getResource("../img/gesicht.PNG").toExternalForm());
```

The last variant does not work and I do not understand why. Can someone explain me as?

Image in img-Folder, outside src folder

```
      Image img = new Image(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("../../img/gesicht.png").toExternalForm());
```

I've tried everything. But as soon as the image is outside the src folder, I always get a NullPointerException or a failed URL

Folder-Strucure:

project

- src

  - application

    - Main.java
- img

  - gesicht.png

[Project-Structure with all variants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jawjj.png)

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the image and copy the relative path

Comment: You need to make sure the `img` directory is included on the classpath when running your application. As it looks like said directory is supposed to be a resources directory make sure it is marked as such in your IDE.

Comment: It says `gesicht.png` in your screenshot, not `Unbekannt.PNG` or `icon.png`; furthermore navigating "up" doesn't work for resource paths; use the full path starting at the root of the classpath instead: `new 
    Image(getClass().getResource("/img/gesicht.png").toExternalForm())`

Comment: please read the api doc for class.getResource - it explains exactly how the path must be constructed ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `img` folder is a resource folder.
then :

```
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource("/img/gesicht.png").toExternalForm());
```

I think the relative path starts with the root and not from where the source file is.

Comment: Ah alright ! thanks for the note. I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank for your note. But it do not work. My im Folder in a resource folder. And getClass  give the Main-Class. getResourc searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class. So it shut be /../../img/gesicht.png. But it do not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution:

1. Add img-Folder as resource-Folder
2. getResource() dont work! But:

Image img = new Image("file:img/gesicht.png");
primaryStage.getIcons().add(img);

Alternative:
Image image = new Image(new File("img/gesicht.png").toURI().toString());